# Preventing ajax calls from being hijacked

Tags: php, ajax

I've run into this issue several times and have never come up with an elegant solution, so I'm hoping that I have just missed it in my hours of Googling.

**Situation:** I have an AJAX endpoint that submits data. The javascript is hosted/generated on my server (think Google Analytics). I have no way of validating said data, aside from checking that it's a valid email address syntactically. I want to prevent a script from calling the endpoint endlessly.

**Attempted solutions / why they won't necessarily work:**

- Limit calls by IP / Can't always predict the total # of calls over a period of time, especially since IPs can be proxied and/or several people may be behind one IP
- Generate tokens / Can literally be viewed in the source and simply scraped up before re-submitting
- `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` / Totally spoofable

I'm no security expert, but I know that this is a vulnerability that would easily skew data in an environment where some precision is needed.

Comment: You need to provide your code so we can see what you are doing

Comment: @cmorrissey there is no code yet; it's conceptual. All that I would have is literally `$.post('/ajax', { email: 'foo@bar.com', something: 'yes' });`

Comment: you could set a `session` variable when the script is loaded if you enable your server to process .js files as php you can then check to make sure this is set when data is submitted and then set another variable to prevent multiple submissions